# import font in Gnuplot: strange result

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the fontfile option to import a font in gnuplot. The font I selected is similar to a computer modern font, but I obtain a very different font. 
Here is my code

```
reset 
set term postscript enhanced eps fontfile "/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.pfb" "lmr8"
set output "comparison_inside_fields.eps"
set key spacing 1.5
normTemp=2*pi*750*1E+12

set xlabel "{/lmr8=20 t} ({/lmr8=18 s})"
set ylabel "Re({/lmr8=18 E}_{/lmr8=12 1}) ({/lmr8=18 V/m})" font "lmr8,17"

set logscale y
set yrange [50:1000]
set size 0.65
set tics front
set autoscale xfixmax


plot "Analytic_EField_linear_PW1000.dat" u ($1/normTemp):($2) w l lw 3.0 lc rgb "red" title "E_{1} equa-diff", "EField_linear_PW1000.txt" u ($1):($2) w l lw 3.0 lc rgb "blue" title "E_{1} CST", "exponential_linear.dat" u ($1/normTemp):($2) w l lt 2 lw 1.0 lc rgb "black" notitle`
```

and here is the image:

[image]

Comment: That is the same (Courier/Monospace or similar) font that shows up when my system (Mac) is unable to display a font included in an .eps by gnuplot. gv usually gets the font correct, though, which confuses me a bit. Have you used this technique successfully with other latex fonts? Have you tried using the epslatex terminal?

Comment: I try with an another one and same results. It is strange because I receive no error message (If I mistake the name I receive one). It does not work in epslatex

Comment: What does not work in epslatex?

Comment: I have nothing written nor label neither legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font name is `LMRoman8`, and not `lmr8`. Use e.g. `kfontview` or `head -1 .../lmr8.pfb` to see the font name.

So a rather minimal example taken from your script would be:

```
reset 
set term postscript enhanced eps fontfile "/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.pfb" "LMRoman8"
set output "comparison_inside_fields.eps"

set xlabel "{/LMRoman8=20 t} ({/LMRoman8=18 s})"
set ylabel "Re({/LMRoman8=18 E}_{/LMRoman8=12 1}) ({/LMRoman8=18 V/m})" font "LMRoman8,17"
plot x title "E_{1} equa-diff"
```

Result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]

The result is ok, but I would recommend you to use the `epslatex` terminal, which provides much nicer typesetting. Here an examplary document similar to yours:

```
basename = 'epslatex-test'
set terminal epslatex standalone header '\usepackage{lmodern}'
set output basename.'.tex'

set xlabel '$t$ (s)'
set ylabel 'Re$(E_1)$ (V/m)' offset 1
plot x

set output
system(sprintf('latex %s.tex && dvips %s.dvi && ps2pdf %s.ps && pdfcrop --margins 1 %s.pdf %s.pdf',\
       basename, basename, basename, basename, basename))
```

[image]

Instead of using the `header` option you can also write all the packages and settings you want for all image into a file `gnuplot.cfg`, which will be included automatically, if available.

Comment: Thank you. Epslatex produces also a tex file. it seems more complex to put inside the document (it is for an article)

Comment: If the plots are to be used in a different document, I would suggest you to use the `standalone` option and compile each image separately, see the edited answer.